# slideDown Jquery CSS set up?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation, slidedown

Okay, so I have a menu that I want to slide down from underneath another menu. I'm not sure I'm setting up the jQuery correctly. I'll post an image link of the design.

[navigation set up design](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v88/Nesso/ScreenShot2013-03-06at44128PM_zpsae8db47c.png)

What I have is a section of a head all contained in divs and what not. There is a menu underneath the one shown (the light grey part at the bottom) and it is contained in another div (#subMenu) for querying. Basically I want the one underneath to slide down and reveal itself by clicking a link on that top menu shown in the image.

The menu underneath is layered and positioned on the page via the z-index and relativity. It is named #SubMenu and is 60px high and the query setup is as so:

```
$(document).ready(function()){
//build a var to target #subMen div
var menu = $j('#subMenu')
//use click from link id
$('#menu-item-47').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //if the menu is visible slide it up
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
        {
            menu.slideUp(50);
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }
        //otherwise, slide menu down
        else
        {
            menu.SlideDown(50);
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
});

});
```

Yet after plugging and setting up in wordpress I'm not getting any effects upon clicking the link. I may be installing it in wordpress wrong but I'd rather start from square one with problem solving. As there would be no point if the code is set up wrong.

Comment: What does the js console say?

Comment: It says that there is a syntax error on the 1st line for some reason or it will say there is an error on the line I gave the variable menu to.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in `slideDown`.

Also, you should be using `jQuery` instead of `$` because WP uses `.noConflict()` by default.

Comment: Oh crap! Thanks, Ill try this out! Thanks! I'll come back if something else occurs.